# can not resolve junit from parent

Tags: maven, junit

I have parent project and 4 children modules. I have added junit dependency in parent like this:

```
<dependencys>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencys>
```

Now I am testing some java classes in childreen modules and I get error messsage in eclipse:

```
The import org.junit cannot be resolved
```

Do I have to add junit dependency to all children modules or what is the best practice?
[image]

Comment: Do you have imported the class in a test (located at src/test/java)?

Comment: @Jens yes import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

Comment: Where is the class located?

Comment: @Jens in src/test/java

Comment: By the way i have added junit dependency in    <dependencyManagement> in parent project.

Comment: You need to put junit dependency under <dependencies> in parent pom. <dependencyManagement> just enforces unique versions across all child modules. But in that case the dependencies will have to declared manually in child modules.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/maven-dependencymanagement-vs-dependencies-tags check this for difference between `dependencyManagement` and `dependencies` tags

Answer (score 0):

move junit dependency from dependencyManagement to  dependencies should solve the problem